# Record label in Spotify Apps API

Tags: api, desktop, spotify

Is there a way to get the record label with an album lookup in the Spotify Apps API?

or in maybe there's another way to get the record label?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the label in advance, you can search by label using the [advanced search syntax](http://www.spotify.com/se/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/). Other than that, there's no way at the moment to get that information.